# Alter menu title or add menu item programmatically?

Tags: 7, navigation

I want to create link to user from the menu created by UI. I tried with hook_menu but the link is 'user', but it doesn't work, because don't want to create new page. I would like to alter title or add menu item programmicaly to use First name in the the menu title.

What i know is the 'mlid' = '3228' and menu name is 'menu-user-links-top'

PS. I also tried with hook_menu_link_alter but it doesn't work, for all users (the first name appears after pressing edit menu and uses only admin's first name).

Comment: are you want to change the menu-item to `user-name`?, So whenever user logged in the menu-item(its title) gets change to registered username.

Comment: yes, for the user first name, actually, but it doesn't matter really. I need to find way to create menu item to user page without hook_menu or hook_menu_link_alter becuase it doesn't work. I noticed that I can use theme funtions, but  I would preffer my own module.

Comment: but how are you providing first-name to drupal site? Drupal has only one thing `Username` that is a one `string` like you can see in Stackexchange site. Does your site have provision to provide first-name and last-name separately when user creates his/her account?

Comment: did you get my point in previous comment, we can fetch the `user-name` based on the uid, and can show it in-place of menu-item as that variable is already there in Drupal. But, there is nothing called first-name and last-name part of that username variable in drupal, as far as I know. If there is, I am not aware presently.

Comment: Hi, I don't see problem with user-name or account fields. I know to access them, the problem is how to create PHP menu item title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if I take the `User-Menu` in bartik theme, and I want to change the `My Account` menu-title with `Username`, So whenever, the user logged in, instead of `My Account` that menu-item shown the `Username`.

**Image-1: Default menu-item**

> [image]

**Image-2: After the code**

[image]

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) {
    global $user;
    if ($item['href'] == 'user') {
      $item['title'] = t($user->name);
    }
}
```

Now, same way as shown in the above code, you can change the apply the `href` of any particular menu-item and there it will show the `user-name` instead of the menu-title.

I am not sure are you looking for this or other, but this is the straight code to change the men-item with username.

Comment: Question answered :) I can also use this hook in module. Thank you

Comment: Generally you can put in `template.php` file as it is very small code, but if you want you can put in module also. But remember to find the correct `href` of the menu-item which you are targeting. You can use devel module for that.